# How can I solve the problem of Compose Navigation repeatedly creating destination combination items?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

**MainActivity** contains five pages built using Compose. Navgation will repeatedly create destination, causing the screen to load repeatedly. I added Log to two places in **ArticlePage.kt** to print the log.The following is the log corresponding to each operation.

1. The first generation of the application to open the log is

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created
2. Log after performing refresh operation

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change
3. Log when Navigation to other screen

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change
4. Log when switch to the ArticlePage again

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change

   D/ArticlePage: ArticlePage page is created

   I/ArticlePage: articles data change

Because every time the log prints **articles data change**, it means that my screen needs to be refreshed once, and the animation in the screen will be loaded repeatedly. Very influential to use.How can I set it up to avoid page repeated loading.

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
HomePages.forEachIndexed { index, screen ->
            selected = currentDestination == screen.route,
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
```

**MainActivityNavigation.kt**

```kotlin
NavHost(navController, startDestination = HomePage.ArticlePage.route) {
        composable(HomePage.ArticlePage.route) {
            val viewModel:ArticleVM = hiltViewModel()
            ArticlePage(activity,viewModel) //The parameter activity is MainActivity
        }
    }
```

**ArticlePage.kt**

This is a mixed screen containing View and Compose.FragmentArticlesBinding contains a RecyclerView and refresh control widget

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun ArticlePage(
        activity: MainActivity,
        articleVM: ArticleVM,
    ) {

        Log.d("ArticlePage", "ArticlePage page is created")

        AndroidViewBinding(factory = FragmentArticlesBinding::inflate) {
                ...... //init refresh

                // Directly monitor article data changes
                articleVM.articles.observe(activity) {
                    Log.i("ArticlePage", "articles data change")
                    ......... //other operations
                }
            }
    }
```

**ArticleVM.kt**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ArticleVM @Inject constructor() : BaseVM() {
    // article List declare
    val articles = MutableLiveData<ReturnList<ArticleDetail>>()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `combinable items`?

Comment: Use Compose to declare the interface

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46998172/136490478-8cc0e50c-0af0-4d62-89ad-f9b0542e1e1d.mp4

Comment: I gave a video link, you can see that the animation on the interface is repeatedly started due to the repeated loading of the destination, which greatly affects the user experience.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491725/3585796). If it didn't help, please add your code with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I read the link you gave but it doesn't seem to apply to my question. I re-edited the question and I would like to trouble you to read it again.

Comment: I am using compose navigation in my project and the only issue I have is that it is a bit weird how `lauchSingleTop` flag works (or it doesn't?). I find myself writing `popUpTo(...)` all the time. It looks like I have the same setup as you do with several tabs on the Home Screen, although each of my tab is contained in its own nested navigation graph and I do not use saveState / restoreState flags... What's your version of navigation? I'm on 2.4.0-alpha10, and I remember it did have bugs in previous iterations.

Comment: I used the same version as you

Comment: I refer to the official [Jetchat](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetchat) sample, and debug in the official sample and found that it also appears when I navigate between different destinations The problem of the destination being created repeatedly, it is mentioned in the official document about [NavHost](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost)'s explanation:As you navigate between composables, the content of the NavHost is automatically recomposed.I don't know if this is the reason why the destination is repeatedly created.

Comment: I have temporarily abandoned this part of the migration to Compose-Navigation, and for the time being, I still use the original ViewPager2+BottomNavigationBar solution