# Why the view keeps flashing when using jetpack navigation with Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a login scren and when the login is successful and the view model updates the mutable state variable, my expectation is that a new composable function is called to show a new screen and the login one is removed. The problem is that when the new screen (aka `Screen.AccountsScreen`) is shown, its content keeps flashing/redrawing and same thing happen with the login form which never gets destroyed (I know this because the log message 'Recomponing...' gets printed endless). I assume this happens because the `isLoginSuccessful` state is always true. It seems I need an event that can be consumed only once, is this correct? If so, how can I do that?

`LoginViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

  var isLoginSuccessful by mutableStateOf(false)
  var errorMessage by mutableStateOf("")
  
  fun onLoginClick(email: String, password:String) {
    errorMessage = ""
    if (credentialsValid(email, password)) {
      isLoginSuccessful = true
    } else {
      errorMessage = "Email or password invalid"
      isLoginSuccessful = false
    }
  }
}
```

`LoginScreen.kt`

```
@Composable
fun loginScreen(
  navController: NavController,
  viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
  println("Recomponing...")
  // Here gos the code for the login form
  
  if (viewModel.isLoginSuccessful) {
    navController.navigate(Screen.AccountsScreen.route) {
      popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route) { inclusive = true }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did my answer solve your question? If so, please accept it using a checkmark under the votes counter. Otherwise, let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: @Pylyp Dukhov My screens also flash sometimes and I have not yet found out the reason. in my case the action to navigate happens inside a lambda on button click. Afaik I dont need to use a Launched effect in this case as the lambda is not part of the composition but when it happens the state of my composition is lost and I get a screen flash. not sure what I am missing

Comment: @quealegriamasalegre it's hard to say, please reduce your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post an other question, as it doesn't seems to be related to this one.

Comment: The thing Is I am not able to reproduce it consistently. I will try to create the conditions to make it happen consistently and post the question then

Answer (score 19):

Composite navigation recomposes both disappearing and appearing views during transition. This is the expected behavior.

You're calling navigate on each recomposition. Your problem lays in these lines:

```
if (viewModel.isLoginSuccessful) {
    navController.navigate(Screen.AccountsScreen.route) {
        popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route) { inclusive = true }
    }
}
```

You shouldn't change state directly from view builders. In this case [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) should be used:

```
if (viewModel.isLoginSuccessful) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        navController.navigate(Screen.AccountsScreen.route) {
            popUpTo(Screen.LoginScreen.route) { inclusive = true }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out more in side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Comment: You can't launch a composable function inside non composable function.

Comment: you can use LaunchedEffect(viewModel.isLoginSuccessful) { } as the key to execute the navController call

Answer (score 1):

For me, I see flicker because the activity background is white, but I am on dark mode.

Change your app theme to daynight, try adding

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

and change your theme to

```
<style name="Theme.MyStockApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: indeed this is the problem in my case! 
But adding this theme didn't fix the issue. What I mean is that I see this flashing thing when in dark mode but not when it's not

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, a "non hacky" solution has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248016/8133711

Answer (score 0):

I Got this same problem i got a similiar solution on [this site][1]

```
val lazyitems = remember {
pager(pagingconfig(/* ... */)) { /* ... */ }
    .flow
    .cachedin(viewmodelscope)
    .collectaslazypagingitems()}


class mainscreenviewmodel : viewmodel() {
val pagingflow = pager(pagingconfig(/* ... */)) { /* ... */ }
    .flow
    .cachedin(viewmodelscope)}
```

Comment: @composable

fun mainscreen(
    viewmodel = viewmodel<mainscreenviewmodel>()
) {
    val lazyitems = viewmodel.pagingflow.collectaslazypagingitems()
}

this is the rest of the code