# Navigate with Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was testing Compose and navigation and noticed strange behavior *(nav ver: androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10)* 
In this example, is a screen to check if the app is up to date or not (boolean var in the code for simple test), and if yes, navigate to other screen. 
The big issue I found here was that when automating the navigation, the second screen switches to the first one very quickly. But if the navigation is done with the click of a button, for example, nothing strange happens...

MainActivity file code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = "first_screen"
                    ) {
                        composable(route = "first_screen") {
                            FirstScreen(navController)
                        }
                        composable(route = "second_screen") {
                            SecondScreen(navController)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FirstScreen file code:

```
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val isAppUpdated = true // switch case
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar {
                Text(text = "First Screen Bar")
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "First Screen",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4
            )
            if (!isAppUpdated) OutdatedApp()
            else {
                // Two options to navigate: with compose button or automatically
                // UpdatedApp {
                //     navigateToSecondScreen(navController)
                // }
                navigateToSecondScreen(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OutdatedApp() {
    Text(
        text = "Your app is out of date, consider updating it!",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
    )
}

@Composable
fun UpdatedApp(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = { onClick() }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Navigate to Second Screen",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.button
        )
    }
}

private fun navigateToSecondScreen(navController: NavController) {
    navController.navigate(route = "second_screen") {
        launchSingleTop
        popUpTo(route = "first_screen") { inclusive = true }
    }
}
```

SecondScreen file code:

```
@Composable
fun SecondScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar {
                Text(text = "Second Screen Bar")
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Second Screen",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: automatic] [image: manual]

Can anyone explain what happens in these cases? 
And any solution to implement this logic?

**EDIT** 
I did another test without **Scaffold** *on FirstScreen* and it looks like this problem didn't happen...

**SOLUTION** 
[Philip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491725/11255734) 
[LaunchedEffect's documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491725/3585796) answer your question?

Comment: Right answer! The problem has been fixed with **LaunchedEffect()**

Comment: Thank your for your upvote. You can delete this question now as it's a duplicate so it won't help anyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the view keeps flashing when using jetpack navigation with Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487112/why-the-view-keeps-flashing-when-using-jetpack-navigation-with-compose)