# MutableState continuously emitting data

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am facing one strange issue. I am trying to make login screen screen and once login is successful i am navigating user to home screen.

So issue is that after successful login `navigateToDashboard`  is continuously emitting data.
The user is navigated to home screen but in logs it continuously prints **called**. Also i am not able go back from home screen.

**ViewModel**

```
private var _navigateToDashboard: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
var navigateToDashboard: StateFlow<Boolean> = _navigateToDashboard

fun loginUser() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        isLoading.value = true
        try {
            val response = repo.loginUsers(email = email.value, password = password.value)
            pref.storePrefValue(UserPreferences.token, response.data?.authToken ?: "")
            pref.storePrefValue(
                UserPreferences.loginData,
                AppUtility.modelToJson(response) ?: ""
            )
            isLoading.value = false
            _navigateToDashboard.value = true
            Timber.e("ho")
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            isLoading.value = false
            Timber.e(exception)
        }
    }
}
```

**Login Screen**

```
Column(
    Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight().padding(40.dp),
    ) {
    val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val navigateToDashboard by authViewModel.navigateToDashboard.collectAsState()

    if (navigateToDashboard) {
        Timber.e("called")
        navController.popBackStack()
        navController.navigate("home")
    } else {

        AppTextInput(
            "Email Id",
            value = authViewModel.email.value,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(top = 20.dp)
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            }),
        ) {
            authViewModel.setEmail(it)
        }
        AppTextInput(
            "Password",
            value = authViewModel.password.value,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(top = 20.dp),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                keyboardController?.hide()
            }), visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
        ) {
            authViewModel.setPassword(it)
        }
      
        LoadingButton(
            isLoading = authViewModel.isLoading.value,
            title = "Login",
            boxModifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
            buttonModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            authViewModel.loginUser()

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the view keeps flashing when using jetpack navigation with Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487112/why-the-view-keeps-flashing-when-using-jetpack-navigation-with-compose)

Comment: As it helped you, please upvote =) And you can delete this question as it's a duplicate.