# In Android jetpack compose, how to move the screen when I log in?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager

    @Inject
    lateinit var settingsDataStore: SettingsDataStore

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        connectivityManager.registerConnectionObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        connectivityManager.unregisterConnectionObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screen.Login.route) {
                    composable(
                        route = Screen.Login.route
                    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                        val factory = HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, navBackStackEntry)
                        val viewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel(key = "LoginViewModel", factory = factory)
                        LoginScreen(
                            isNetworkAvailable = connectivityManager.isNetworkAvailable.value,
                            onNavigateToHomeScreen = navController::navigate,
                            viewModel = viewModel
                        )
                    }

                    composable(
                        route = Screen.Home.route
                    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                        val factory = HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, navBackStackEntry)
                        val viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel(key = "HomeViewModel", factory = factory)

                        HomeScreen(

                        )
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginScreen**

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    isNetworkAvailable: Boolean,
    onNavigateToHomeScreen: (String) -> Unit,
    viewModel: LoginViewModel
) {

    val loading = viewModel.loading.value
    val user = viewModel.user.value

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        if (!loading && user == null) {
            Button(onClick = { viewModel.onTriggerEvent(LoginEvent.AuthStateEvent) }) {
                Column(

                ) {
                    Text(text = "Log in")
                }
            }
        }else {
            user?.let {
                val route = Screen.Home.route
                onNavigateToHomeScreen(route)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val postLogin: PostLogin,
    private val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
) : ViewModel() {

    val user: MutableState<User?> = mutableStateOf(null)

    val loading = mutableStateOf(false)

    val onLoad: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun onTriggerEvent(event: LoginEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                when(event) {
                    is LoginEvent.AuthStateEvent -> {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Phase 1")
                        if (user.value == null) {
                            val auth: Auth = Auth([***AuthData***])
                            postAuth(auth)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "launchJob: Exception: ${e}, ${e.cause}")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun postAuth(auth: Auth) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Phase 2")
        postLogin.execute(auth, connectivityManager.isNetworkAvailable.value).onEach { dataState ->
            loading.value = dataState.loading

            dataState.data?.let { data ->
                user.value = data
                Log.d(TAG,"Phase 3")
                Log.d(TAG,"User Data File")
            }

            dataState.error?.let { error ->
                Log.d(TAG, "postAuth: ${error}")

            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

**LoginEvent**

```
sealed class LoginEvent {

    object AuthStateEvent: LoginEvent()

}
```

**PostLogin**

```
class PostLogin(
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val authDtoMapper: AuthDtoMapper,
    private val userDtoMapper: UserDtoMapper
) {
    fun execute(
        auth: Auth,
        isNetworkAvailable: Boolean
    ): Flow<DataState<User>> = flow {
        //auth -> authDto -> InterActions -> userDto -> user
        try {
            emit(DataState.loading())
            delay(1000)

            if (isNetworkAvailable) {
                val networkUser = postLoginFromNetwork(auth)

                if (networkUser != null) {
                    emit(DataState.success(networkUser))
                }else {
                    emit(DataState.error<User>("User data is null"))
                }
            }else {
                emit(DataState.error<User>("Unable to connect network"))
            }

        }catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(DataState.error<User>(e.message?: "Unknown Error"))
        }
    }

    private suspend fun postLoginFromNetwork(auth: Auth): User {
        return userDtoMapper.mapToDomainModel(apiService.login(authDtoMapper.fromDomain(auth)))
    }
}
```

**HomeScreen**

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "HomeScreen",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 40.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Hello, I made the above code go to `HomeScreen` when login is successful by pressing the `Login` button on `LoginScreen`.

It was confirmed that the communication was smooth and the value was also brought.

However, when I tried debugging, I confirmed that this part was repeatedly done on Login Screen.

```
user?.let {
    val route = Screen.Home.route
    onNavigateToHomeScreen(route)
}
```

As you can see, when the user has a value, the screen is moved, but that part is repeatedly done, so the `HomeScreen` screen glitters like a flash.

That's why I'm asking you this question. When the value changes after communication, please tell me how to move the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the view keeps flashing when using jetpack navigation with Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487112/why-the-view-keeps-flashing-when-using-jetpack-navigation-with-compose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LauchedEffect

```
LaunchedEffect(user){
   user.let {
      navController.navigate("")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I use that, just navigate to screen, not flash. Thanks