# Viewmodel instantiated in Compose with hiltviewmodel() called multiple times

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am trying to open a compose detail page with Viewmodel added using hiltviewmodel()
The viewmodel has a paging data state and an API call result state which is needed to show the updated data along with the list.But when I navigate to the detail page, the viewmodel methods are called multiple times, even the init {} block also. Anyone facing same issue like this, or got any solution?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    Name: String = ""
) {
    val lazyArticleList = dashboardViewModel.articlePages.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val dashState = dashboardViewModel.dashboardState.value
}
```

Comment: Most probably it's related to how you call `navigate`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491725/3585796)

Comment: Thanks for the link @PylypDukhov. But I am calling the next screen from a lazycolumn cell click event. I am using a single Navhost for navigating. Any idea?

Comment: No idea, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: print dashboardViewModel instance hashcode inside composable method and check it is same or different. May be system is creating new viewmodel(internally as default fallback while get exist instance) while retrieving  existing instance of view model and you are confused from logs.

Comment: Yes @d.k. I checked the hashcode its same but the init block of viewmodel is executed many times.Is this due to using hiltviewmodel()?

Comment: I found this link with the same scenario https://www.javafixing.com/2021/10/fixed-why-new-viewmodel-is-created-in.html. Is this same when using hilt viewmodel? Please help guys

Comment: yes @Brijosh Mohan, I think this is normal behavior of kotlin. When we create class object then constructor and init block normally called.

So there is no issue with your viewmodel object it is same persisted with your compose. You are confused due to init block called.

Comment: @Brijosh Mohan assume hiltviewmodel() pass viewmodel object to system to store it for this compose and system checked if already viewmodel exist for compose then return existed object and discard passed object otherwise save this passed object.
So you see init block call due to passed new object every time recomposition happen. Hope, It is clear to you now.

Comment: I have same issue. any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing the ViewModel as the default argument, try initializing the ViewModel before and pass it as the argument later. It's possible that the ViewModel is being instantiating twice when your `DashboardScreen` composable is recomposed.

i.e change your composable to something like this

```
fun DashboardScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel,
    name: String = ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple calls of the init method of ViewModel happen due to navigation in Composable. When you navigate in the composable a recomposition happens and the composable tries to navigate again. To prevent this behavior you can use `LaunchEffect` composable.

I am collecting my state and making navigation decisions based on the success state. In this approach, I've faced the same issue of multiple init function calls of `viewmodel`.

```
val signInResult by viewModel.signInResult.collectAsState()

when (signInResult) {
 is ViewState.Success -> navController.navigate(route = ScreenRoutes.BOT.name) { popUpTo(0) }
 is ViewState.Error -> {
  Toast.makeText(
   context,
   (signInResult as ViewState.Error).message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  isLoading = false
  }

  ViewState.Loading -> isLoading = true
  ViewState.Ideal -> isLoading = false
}
```

I fix the issue by using `LauchedEffect`. I am using a dynamic value as a key because `LaunchedEffect` runs when the composition is completed and it will not run on re-composition if the key has the same value so when my state changes from `Loading` to `Success` my LaunchedEffect runs again and navigate to the other screen and `LaunchedEffect` will not run again because the key is same which is a `SuccessState`.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = signInResult is ViewState.Success) {
 when (signInResult) {
  is ViewState.Success -> navController.navigate(route = 
 ScreenRoutes.BOT.name) { popUpTo(0) }
  is ViewState.Error -> {
   Toast.makeText(
    context,
    (signInResult as ViewState.Error).message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   isLoading = false
   }

   ViewState.Loading -> isLoading = true
   ViewState.Ideal -> isLoading = false
 }
}
```