# Composable is keep refreshing in infinite loop

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

StateFlow state's change is keep updating even there is no push inside composable.

```
@Composable
fun ScreenController(
  viewModel: SyncViewModel, log: Logger,
  navigateToLogin: () -> Unit,
  navigateToSync: () -> Unit,
  navigateToAttendance: () -> Unit,
  navigateToDashBoard: () -> Unit,
 ) {

val state by viewModel.userCurrentState.collectAsState()
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    viewModel.getUserState()
}

state.let {
    if (!it.isDefault) {
        if (!it.isUserLoggedIn) {
            navigateToLogin()
        } else if (!it.isDataSyncedForToday) {
            navigateToSync()
        } else if (!it.isAttendanceMarked) {
            navigateToAttendance()
        } else {
            navigateToDashBoard()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This compose is keep calling navigateToLogin method, even though the method to get user's current state is called only once(viewModel.getUserState()) inside the launch effect.

Below is the code of NavHost

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(navController, startDestination = FULL_SCREEN) {
         composable(route = FULL_SCREEN) {
              ScreenController(
                        syncViewModel,
                        log,
                        navigateToLogin = { navController.navigate(LOGIN_SCREEN) },
                        navigateToSync = { navController.navigate(DATA_SYNC) },
                        navigateToAttendance = { navController.navigate(ATTENDANCE_SCREEN) },
                        navigateToDashBoard = { navController.navigate(BASE_DASHBOARD) }
                    )
                }

                composable(route = LOGIN_SCREEN) {
                    LoginScreen(navController, loginViewModel, log)
                }
            }
```

Due to this, the LoginScreen composable keeps on recomposing itself due to the state value sending the change events even if they are not modified.

So, I am trying to understand why state value is keep updating and how?

I have tried to make the state as life cycle aware for the particular composable.

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val lifecycleAwareLoginFlow = remember(viewModel.userCurrentState, lifecycleOwner) {
    viewModel.userCurrentState.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
}
val state: UserAppState by lifecycleAwareLoginFlow.collectAsState(initial = UserAppState())
```

But still, the state value change is happening.

Adding more code -

```
class SyncViewModel(
 private val syncRepository: SyncRepository,
log: Logger
) : ViewModel() {

  private val mutableUserState: MutableStateFlow<UserAppState> =
    MutableStateFlow(UserAppState())
  val userCurrentState: StateFlow<UserAppState> =  
       mutableUserState

 fun getUserState(): Job {
    return viewModelScope.launch {
        val isUserLoggedIn = syncRepository.isUserLoggedIn()
        val isSyncDone = syncRepository.isRequiredAPIsSynced()
        val isAttendanceMarked = 
        syncRepository.isAttendanceMarked()
        log.d("App State $isUserLoggedIn, $isSyncDone, 
         $isAttendanceMarked")
        mutableUserState.update {
            it.copy(
                isDefault = false,
                isUserLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn,
                isDataSyncedForToday = isSyncDone,
                isAttendanceMarked = isAttendanceMarked,
            )
        }
    }
}
data class UserAppState(
  val isDefault: Boolean = true,
  val isUserLoggedIn: Boolean = true,
  val isDataSyncedForToday: Boolean = true,
  val isAttendanceMarked: Boolean = true,
)
```

Comment: can you try `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` rather than `collectAsState()`

Comment: It's not helping either.

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491725/3585796)

Comment: do check this https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/49c0477dd877453483d0436fedf56e63030811a9/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/JetsnackNavGraph.kt#L62 if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the state value should be observed only once, so I have moved the navigation logic inside the Launch effect.

```
state.let {
if (!it.isDefault) {
    LaunchedEffect(it) {
     if (!it.isUserLoggedIn) {
        navigateToLogin()
     } else if (!it.isDataSyncedForToday) {
        navigateToSync()
     } else if (!it.isAttendanceMarked) {
        navigateToAttendance()
     } else {
        navigateToDashBoard()
     }
   }
```

With this, the state change is not pushed again, this is a workaround for me and can help someone like me, please share the correct solution for the same.

Comment: you should have a look at this https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3.

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you for sharing the details. But the colllect as life cycle aware is not helping here. If I dont have navigation then the state change is working fine. Not sure when the navigation root changes the old page state got triggered.

Comment: And if you see, I have already mentioned the  state is already life cycle aware. I can’t use cold flow inside view model, due to the code is being shared in multiplatform.

Comment: ha. got it. i was not aware of kmm